# Send the response as key value pair from Spring controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In our application we are getting the request object from third party as form data. We are processing the form data in Spring controller and send the response back. In spring controller we have wrote the logic like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/oci/html/setup", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
produces = {MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE }, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE })
@ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public String handleOciSetUpRequest1(OciSetupRequest reqObject)
{

    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled())
    {
        LOG.debug("Oci Setup Request Object: " + reqObject.toString());
    }

    final OciSetupResponse response = getOciService().processOciSetUpRequest(reqObject);

    return response.toString();

}
```

Request Object:

```
identity: 1234
sharedSecret: password
```

Expected Response object:

```
SessionId=1236547878
URL=https://sample.com
```

Here we need to send the response in the form of key value pair html response. Anyone can help on this
How to send the html response as key-value pair from Spring controller.

If sample code provided will be appreciated....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide the source code of OciSetupResponse

Comment: What is the actual output of your controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you try to return in a response body, the best would be by means of a rest controller, and also add exception handling, with what you would have:

```
@RestController
public class SomeClassController {

    @PostMapping("/oci/html/setup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> reportRecords(OciSetupRequest reqObject) {
     Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        try {
             if (LOG.isDebugEnabled())
             {
                LOG.debug("Oci Setup Request Object: " + reqObject.toString());
             }

             final OciSetupResponse response = getOciService().processOciSetUpRequest(reqObject);
             response.put("SessionId", "1236547878");
             response.put("URL", "https://sample.com");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.put("message", e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hello Edy Huiza, Thanks for your reply. I have tried with your code, but its returning following error.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.HashMap

Comment: So, I have modified method return type to String and send response as string object like response.toString(). After the changes its working

Answer (score 0):

Use a map:

```
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, String> handleOciSetUpRequest1(OciSetupRequest reqObject)
{

    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled())
    {
        LOG.debug("Oci Setup Request Object: " + reqObject.toString());
    }

    final OciSetupResponse response = getOciService().processOciSetUpRequest(reqObject);

    Map<String, String> responseMap - new HashMap();
    map.put("SessionId", "someValue");
    map.put("URL", "someValue");

    return responseMap; 
    //returns JSON {"SessionId":"someValue", "URL":"someValue"}
}
```